# Do potion effects affect the ender dragon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am at the ender dragon and have tons of Potions of instant damage. I never got into range, but do the effects even do anything?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon) under "Bugs":

> Potions have no effect on the ender dragon.

So, to answer the question: No. But this might change in future versions.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now that I know that, what do I do with the potions?

Comment: Chuck 'em at spiders!

Comment: Drink 'em! Duh!

Comment: You cant drink splash potions.

Comment: And there are no spiders in the end

Comment: This is officially working as intended. Your Link doesn't holds the information anymore, here is a better one: https://bugs.mojang.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MC-30466