# Does Strength affect the Ender dragon in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can Strength affect an Ender dragon if I use a lingering potion while battling it? Considering I know that when you throw a potion at it it does nothing but do lingering versions of the potion affect it in `v1.9` or `v1.10`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do potion effects affect the ender dragon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102617/do-potion-effects-affect-the-ender-dragon)

Answer (score 1):

No, potion effects from potions will not be applied to both the Enderdragon and the Wither.

The dragon does not make use of the `generic.attackDamage` attribute, which means Strength would not work even if it could be applied. The Wither does make use of that attribute, but effects are still not applied to it.

---

As an in-game example using a Wither, the following applies the Strength effect to it:

```
/summon WitherBoss ~ ~1 ~ {NoAI:1b}
/effect @e[type=WitherBoss] minecraft:strength
```

And the following will display all data on the Wither, showing both the lack of an attackDamage modifier as well as the `ActiveEffects` list, despite the above `/effect` command stating it was successful:

```
/entitydata @e[type=WitherBoss,c=1] {}
```